# Multiply all columns in an excel worksheet by the values in the first column

Tags: excel, equation

I have an excel worksheet with 1153 columns. I need the values in each column to be multiplied by those in the first column. I have inserted blank columns between each column to add the results and right now I am doing this by hand, but it is taking too long. Here is an example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Njr.jpg)

EDIT- Right now I am copying the formula $A1*adjacent cell into each blank column and then simply double clicking to population the rest of the column. My hope was that there was an alternative.

Is there VBA code, a macro, or a formula that would make this process faster? Thank you.

Comment: Copy the first cell and then select the others and Paste Special, Multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your looking for some form of direct addressing. For example, the relative cell address "A1" will change if you copy the address to another cell, but the address"$A$1" will always reference cell A1 regardless of where you copy it to.

However you can fix only the row or column with the address "A$1" or "$A1" so that the address will always reference the same row or column, but will update the other as it's copied. In your case you probably want to fix the column with "$A1".

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have $A1 and I can copy that into each blank column. That is what I have been doing up to this point. Perhaps that is the fastest solution.

Comment: @ARob - I think I actually understand your problem now. What you need is a way to enter the formula into 1,153 columns. In that case you need VBA code. Two nested For loops will do the trick. Are there a set number of rows for all columns or does it vary?